# NSTextView Highlighting dont trigger

Tags: python, objective-c, cocoa

I have downloaded: `NSTextView` Highlighting from: [enter link description here](http://www.programmish.com/?p=30)

It works as it should, if you open the app and type the sign "-" it turns red, but then i faced a problem. I wrote: `IBOutlet NSTextView * change_text` inside the **.h** file and wrote inside the **.m** file:

```
-(void)awakeFromNib {



    [text_View setString:@"-"];


}
```

The idea was when the app open it should display the sign "-" as red on the screen. It did display the sign: "-" but without highlighting it, only until i manually clicked on return or space then it turned red. I want it to turn the sign red instead of waiting that someone change the text again. Please help me out

The python script look like:

```
from Foundation import *
from AppKit import *

import objc

class PyObjC_HighlightAppDelegate(NSObject):

    # The connection to our NSTextView in the UI
    highlightedText = objc.IBOutlet()

    # Default font size to use when highlighting
    fontSize = 12

    def applicationDidFinishLaunching_(self, sender):
        NSLog("Application did finish launching.")

    def textDidChange_(self, notification):




        """
        Delegate method called by the NSTextView whenever the contents of the
        text view have changed. This is called after the text has changed and
        been committed to the view. See the Cocoa reference documents:

        http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSText_Class/Reference/Reference.html
        http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTextView_Class/Reference/Reference.html

        Specifically the sections on Delegate Methods for information on additional
        delegate methods relating to text control is NSTextView objects.
        """

        # Retrieve the current contents of the document and start highlighting

        content = self.highlightedText.string()
        self.highlightText(content)

    def setAttributesForRange(self, color, font, rangeStart, rangeLength):
        """
        Set the visual attributes for a range of characters in the NSTextView. If
        values for the color and font are None, defaults will be used.

        The rangeStart is an index into the contents of the NSTextView, and
        rangeLength is used in combination with this index to create an NSRange
        structure, which is passed to the NSTextView methods for setting
        text attributes. If either of these values are None, defaults will
        be provided.

        The "font" parameter is used as an key for the "fontMap", which contains
        the associated NSFont objects for each font style.
        """
        fontMap = {
                    "normal" : NSFont.systemFontOfSize_(self.fontSize),
                    "bold" : NSFont.boldSystemFontOfSize_(self.fontSize)
                    }

        # Setup sane defaults for the color, font and range if no values
        # are provided
        if color is None:
            color = NSColor.blackColor()
        if font is None:
            font = "normal"        

        if font not in fontMap:
            font = "normal"

        displayFont = fontMap[font]

        if rangeStart is None:
            rangeStart = 0

        if rangeLength is None:
            rangeLength = len(self.highlightedText.string()) - rangeStart

        # Set the attributes for the specified character range
        range = NSRange(rangeStart, rangeLength)
        self.highlightedText.setTextColor_range_(color, range)
        self.highlightedText.setFont_range_(displayFont, range)

    def highlightText(self, content):
        """
        Apply our customized highlighting to the provided content. It is assumed that
        this content was extracted from the NSTextView.
        """

        # Calling the setAttributesForRange with no values creates
        # a default that "resets" the formatting on all of the content
        self.setAttributesForRange(None, None, None, None)

        # We'll highlight the content by breaking it down into lines, and
        # processing each line one by one. By storing how many characters
        # have been processed we can maintain an "offset" into the overall
        # content that we use to specify the range of text that is currently
        # being highlighted.
        contentLines = content.split("\n")
        highlightOffset = 0

        for line in contentLines:

            if line.strip().startswith("#"):
                # Comment - we want to highlight the whole comment line
                self.setAttributesForRange(NSColor.greenColor(), None, highlightOffset, len(line))


            elif line.find(":") > -1:
                # Tag - we only want to highlight the tag, not the colon or the remainder of the line
                startOfLine = line[0: line.find(":")]
                yamlTag = startOfLine.strip("\t ")
                yamlTagStart = line.find(yamlTag)
                self.setAttributesForRange(NSColor.blueColor(), "bold", highlightOffset + yamlTagStart, len(yamlTag))

            elif line.strip().startswith("-"):
                # List item - we only want to highlight the dash
                listIndex = line.find("-")
                self.setAttributesForRange(NSColor.redColor(), None, highlightOffset + listIndex, 1)


            # Add the processed line to our offset, as well as the newline that terminated the line
            highlightOffset += len(line) + 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the core issue at hand here is that calling `-[NSTextView setString]` doesn't post the `NSTextDidChangeNotification`, so the code never calls the `textDidChange_` method. So I think the easiest solution is just to post that notification after you set the string. I don't really know PyObjC, but this is how you'd do it in Objective-C:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:NSTextDidChangeNotification object:text_view];
```

I wouldn't recommend calling the method `textDidChange_` method directly, as if you (or any library you use) ever relies on that being called when the text changes, they need to react to the same notification.

Answer (score -2):

Just invoke `textDidChange` in `applicationDidFinishLaunching`, if I understand correctly.

Comment: For the scope of this program, I bet this would be adequate.